# Array allocation

Tags: java, arrays

I am confused what does that mean ::

```
int[] array = new int[0];
```

How many bytes are allocated here? Or nothing is allocated in memory? What is going underneath?

Comment: See [`Why is int[] a = new int[0]; allowed?`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444414/why-is-int-a-new-int0-allowed) for the usage of this.

Answer (score 4):

This is a zero-length array.

How many bytes are allocated is platform specific, but you still have an array here, just a very short one. In general, an array in Java needs

```
fixed overhead + length * componentSize
```

bytes (and then there is maybe some padding).

Also note that since arrays cannot be resized in Java, and a zero-length array cannot have elements updated, this makes those immutable and you don't actually need more than one instance of them in your whole program, so you can use a static singleton like [ArrayUtils.EMPTY_INT_ARRAY](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#EMPTY_INT_ARRAY), saving that "fixed overhead".